# How to ORDER BY a person's first_name but ALSO insert nicknames ASC

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is some example data:

```
nickname    first_name    last_name
=======     =======       =======       
            Charlie       Smith         
            Beta          Jones         
Alpha       Chris         Anderson      
Delta       Nick          Andrews
```

**This is the result I want (first letters are A, B, C, D)**

1. "**A**lpha" Chris Anderson
2. **B**eta Jones
3. **C**harlie Smith
4. "**D**elta" Nick Andrews

My problem is when I run the usual `ORDER BY nickname ASC, first_name ASC` I get this (B, C, A, D):

1. **B**eta Jones
2. **C**harlie Smith
3. "**A**lpha" Chris Anderson
4. "**D**elta" Nick Andrews

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply want `coalesce()`:

```
order by coalesce(nickname, first_name)
```

This assumes that the blank values are `NULL`.  If they are actually empty strings, then:

```
order by coalesce(nullif(nickname, ''), first_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this;)

```
order by (concat(coalesce(nickname, ''), coalesce(first_name, ''), coalesce(last_name, '')))
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e14bae/2)