# Order by nickName if nickName is not null, otherwise order by firstName

Tags: postgresql, repository-pattern, typeorm

I have the same problem [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073728/how-to-order-by-a-persons-first-name-but-also-insert-nicknames-asc)

But I didn't find  any solution to do this with nestJs and postgres with Repository-orm.

this is my code.

```
  const contacts = await this.contactRepository.find({
  order: { nickName: 'ASC', firstName: 'ASC', lastName: 'ASC' },
});
```

Comment: Do you need pure typeorm solution? Or SQL solution will be OK too?

Comment: I have SQL solution in the link I added. I look for typeorm solution. with queryBuilder it's will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `QueryBuilder`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68574221/6676781) answer for more information.

As you correctly suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38073831/6676781), you have to use the *ORDER BY* clause in combination with *COALESCE(...)*.

Example query:

```js
const contacts = await this.contactRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('contact')
  .orderBy('COALESCE(contact.nickName, contact.firstName, contact.lastName)', 'ASC')
  .getMany();
```

Comment: great tnx, how  I can CONCAT firstName with lastName to make the order by lastName,
when there is no nickName and the firstName are equal